# Can you dive into Berlin's Radisson Blu Aquadom?

Tags: hotels, berlin, diving

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to dive into [Radisson Blu's](http://www.radissonblu.de/hotel-berlin) Aquadom. I know that there's a [lift for tourists](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aM6niCCtOII) that takes you "inside" the aquarium, but I'm looking for scuba diving. Does anyone know if it's possible?

Note: consider that I'm a certified diver and that I'm not staying at the hotel, if that's of any importance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being a scuba diver, the first time I saw the pictures from the [Aquarium](http://www.radissonblu.com/hotel-berlin/services), a few month ago, I immediately started researching more details about how to dive there.

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The guests can't go for a dive in the Aquadom, they can just take the elevator inside it.

If you search online for pictures about the Hotel, you may happen to see people diving inside. Actually, those guys are from [Sea Life Berlin](http://www.visitsealife.com/berlin/en/) (the company that manages the Acquadom) and they are normally diving for maintenance of the aquarium (as it happens in every other aquarium, it's not uncommon to see divers cleaning the floors or feeding animals).

Answer (score 7):

The best information I was able to find the answer is: NO.

Aquadom at Radisson in Berlin is managed by [Sea Life Berlin](http://www.visitsealife.com/berlin/en/) which doesn't offer diving as one of the Things to Do in Aquadom.